# Expected number of frog jumps

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There is frog jumping forward on a line. Each jump distance is random with a known cumulative distribution function $F$. What is the expected number of jumps to reach (or go beyond) distance $d$ from the origin?

If there is a Wikipedia or other web page describing the formula in terms of $F$, just give a (deep) link. I'd prefer to have the proof as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $X_i$ denote the distance of jump $i$ of the frog. Each $X_i$ is independent of one-another. The total distance at jump $n$ is then $D_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. Define $\tau$ for $D_\tau$, where $\tau$ is the first time such that $D_\tau\geq d$. You are interested in $E(\tau)$. The distribution of $D_n$ is the $n$-fold convolution of $F$'s: $F_n = (F\star)^n:=F\star F\star\cdots \star F$.

$P(\tau> n) = P(D_n<d)$

Now use $E(\tau)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(\tau> n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(D_n<d)$

Which we can simplify when $F$ is continuous by noting $P(D_n<d)=P(D_n\leq d)=F_n(d)$. I'm not sure if there's any more simplification you can do without an explicit form for $F$.

Comment: A small typo: actually $P(\tau>n)=P(D_n<d).$

Comment: @Byron: whoops! Thanks!

Comment: @Sam: Please fix the typo. This will also change the lower bound of the sum from 1 to 0. Please fix it everywhere.

Comment: Shoudn't $E[\tau]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nP(\tau=n)$?

Answer (score 5):

**Reference:** This problem has been worked out thoroughly if the random walk steps are uniform and continuous. See, for example,

> Russell, K. G. *On the number of uniform random variables which must be added to exceed a given level.*
>   J. Appl. Probab. 20 (1983), no. 1, 172–177.

It is a well-known puzzle to show that the expected number of uniform(0,1) steps 
to exceed level 1 is $\exp(1)$. I was sure that this appears somewhere on this site, but I can't find it.

Comment: Thanks for digging up this related article (+1ed it). Unfortunately your answer doesn't work for arbitrary distributions, so I can't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the frog is jumping forward, the random variable $X$ denoting the distance per jump will always be nonnegative. So we can use the result for expectations of nonnegative random variables, shown and proved here: [Wikipedia's entry on expected values.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Continuous_distribution_taking_non-negative_values) The result gives us that $$E(X) = \int_0^{\infty} \text{Pr}(X \ge x) \; dx = \int_0^{\infty} (1-F(x)) \; dx $$

Now that we have the expected distance per jump, all we have to do is divide the given distance $d$ by $E(X)$ and round appropriately to give us the expected number of jumps.

Comment: Why is it true that if $d/E(x)$ is the expected number of jumps? It's not intuitive to me. Can you please justify?

Comment: Why do I have to round $d/E(x)$ at all? The result can be a non-integer.

Comment: Hey there - you would have to round $d/E(X)$ if you agree with me that the frog can only take integral jumps, and not half-jumps or anything like that. Otherwise, rounding would not be necessary.

Comment: Yes, the frog can only take an integer number of jumps (and the distance of each jump can be any nonnegative real, with the distribution $F$). I'm looking for the expected value of the number of jumps the frog has to take. I fail to see why this has to be an integer, and why rounding is necessary.

Comment: My thinking was this: $d/E(X)$ is the distance divided by the expected distance per jump. You could think about it by dividing a line segment of length $d$ into subsegments of length $E(X)$ -- then the expected number of jumps would be the number of those subsegments, i.e. $d/E(X)$. However, I think Sam's answer above is better, and doesn't use my assumption that $F$ is continuous....

Answer (score -1):

The distribution function defines the probability that the random variable is less than or equal to a given x: $P(n\leq x) = F(x)$. In this case, x is the distance of a single jump.

What we need is the expected value V of the distribution function. To get this, we want the derivative of the distribution function, $f(x) = F'(x)$, which produces a function known as the "probability density function" of x. This function will tell us how likely any given jump is to be x units.

Now, given that, the "expected value" of the random variable is equal to:

[image]

This "expected value", much like the term states, is the long-term average value of X given a sufficiently large number of trials. For a normal distribution, it is *usually* the point at which $f(x)$ is at its peak; however many probability functions are not normal (for instance, the probability of an n-sided die rolled once showing a particular face x is 1/n regardless of x). Now, that equation is the general form. We know that the frog always jumps forward, and thus the jump distance is never negative; therefore, we should actually solve the integral for a lower bound of 0:

$$E[x] = \int_0^\infty xf(x)dx$$

$E[x]$ will be the length of the average jump; it has a roughly 50-50 shot to be higher or lower, and thus given enough jumps, the sum of any n jumps should be $E[x] * n$. Now it's arithmetic; solve $E[x] * n >= d$ for n.

Comment: @DownVoter, care to comment?