# Expected number of jumps to just exceed $(1-\rho)$ quantile in the line segment $[0, 1]$

Tags: algorithms, expectation, conditional-expectation, algorithmic-randomness

Suppose $X$ is random variable from some unknown distribution $f(X)$. I'm given a black-box/algorithm that takes a number $c\;: 0 \leq c < 1$ and outputs a number(randomly generated) using the [truncated distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) $f_c(X)$ where the domain of $X = [c, 1]\; \therefore f_0(X) = f(X)$. Now I need to estimate the $E[\text{count}]$ for the values of $count$ returned by the following code:

Input: rho (where $0<\rho <1$)

$Q(1-\rho)$: Value of [Quantile Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) [$(1-\rho)^{\text{th}}$-quantile] of the distribution function $f_0(X)$

```
int get_count(float rho) {
  float c = 0.0;
  int count = 0;
  while(c < Q(1-rho)) {
    c = blackbox_algo(c);
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

I tried to construct a recurrence by conditional expectation(as generally done in case of geometric distribution) but it seems to be not correct as 
the memoryless property is not valid here. Any help is welcome :)

Disclaimer: It's not a homework problem. I'm a budding researcher in engineering and ran into situation where such kind of problems are arising.
This problem has a similarity with [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198614/expected-number-of-frog-jumps) but these are not identical

Answer (score 1):

You can forget about finding the expected number of steps if you don't know what $f$ is.

**Original question**

It should be obvious that if $f(x) = 0$ for every $x \in [1-ρ,1]$, then your `get_count` will run **forever**. It suggests that making $f$ sufficiently close to zero in that region would make the expected count go to infinity, and in fact this is so.

**Present question**

If you take two distributions with the same cutoff $t = Q(1-ρ)$ but different distribution over $[0,Q(1-ρ)]$, then you'll get different count distributions. Just try for discrete distributions to see why. Say $t = 0.5$, and in one case $X = 0$ whenever $X < t$, and in the other case $X$ is $0$ or $0.1$ with equal probability whenever $X < t$. Then the second case will obviously give a lower expected count because truncation occurs faster.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for your valuable comment ! I've edited the question.

Comment: @aroyc: Now your code doesn't even make sense. Quantile function for **which** distribution?

Comment: thanks again...fixed it :)

Comment: @aroyc: I updated my answer. But seriously what is so secret about $f$ that you cannot tell us?

Comment: @aroyc: You should put your motivation in your question. Sometimes if you try to change your original question into a new one, it becomes a different question, and there's no way anyone would know if you don't state the motivation.

Comment: Well...nothing secret and being a learner I'm open to discuss to fullest clarity :) actually I also don't know about the explicit form of $f$. My intention is to  customize [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198614/expected-number-of-frog-jumps) question to serve my purpose.

Comment: I accept my inability to post the the problem in a correct manner and apologize for that.

Comment: @aroyc: What I mean is that you should tell us all you know about the distribution of $X$. Why is it a blackbox? What does it represent? Is it from a real-world problem? Why should we be interested in the number of steps? Once you answer all these questions, it may become apparent that there is crucial information that was not given in your original question. If there isn't, then my answer completely resolves your question in the negative.

Comment: @aroyc: Anyway that link explains a lot, so you should include it in your question. Notice that Alex R also said in his answer that nothing much can be said without knowing the distribution.

Comment: I've included it before posting my previous comment. Check the "Disclaimer" portion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35679/discussion-between-aroyc-and-user21820).

Comment: @aroyc: Really sorry I didn't notice that extra sentence in your disclaimer.